# I can't install vuetify. error Component name "Home" should always be multi-word vue/multi-word-component-names

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vuex, vuetifyjs3

I can't install vuetify. error Component name "Home" should always be multi-word vue/multi-word-component-names

Below is the full message:
There are uncommitted changes in the current repository, it's recommended to commit or stash them first.
? Still proceed? yes

Installing vue-cli-plugin-vuetify...

up to date, audited 1735 packages in 9s

164 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

17 vulnerabilities (6 moderate, 11 high)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
npm audit fix

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.
✔ Successfully installed plugin: vue-cli-plugin-vuetify

? Choose a preset: Vuetify 2 - Vue CLI (recommended)

Invoking generator for vue-cli-plugin-vuetify...
WARN conflicting versions for project dependency "sass-loader":

```
    - ^12.0.0 injected by generator "undefined"
    - ^10.0.0 injected by generator "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify"

    Using newer version (^12.0.0), but this may cause build errors.
```

⠋ Running completion hooks...
C:\Users\allan\Downloads\Projects\curso-vue\vue-cli\project-plugins\src\views\HomeView.vue
9:11 error Component name "Home" should always be multi-word vue/multi-word-component-names

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)

So far I have tried to change the Component name "Home" to "HomeView" in the homeView.vue

but when trying this, I realize that after trying to install vuetify again, when the process is terminated, the "HomeView" returns to being "Home"

Comment: you're installing it just fine.  the error you have is from eslint.  you can [turn off the rule](https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/multi-word-component-names.html) and the error will go away. it's just a code format recommendation rule so it's ok to turn off.

Comment: You're supposed to not just change a file but commit it. Fwiw, linter rule that causes the problem doesn't serve a good purpose and can be disabled, as long as you're aware of the problem it addresses.

Comment: Please format your code block(s), logs and errors, in order to make your question more readable, and receive better quality answers. For more information, take a look on this link: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks